# Plot output is not being shown when running server

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

In R - I am trying to create a dropdown for my plot built using ggplot. I decided to use the shiny package to do this. I am not sure why, but when the server has launched the dropdown and everything is there but when I try to click different options the plot won't show up. I know my list is currently static - I am just trying to get this to work first before I update that part. I will show my code below. I am trying to filter on the Event column. The event column will have values like "Iowa @ Ohio State", etc.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tcltk)
library(latticeExtra)
library(patchwork)

rm(list=ls())

#new code
# Start with a usual ggplot2 call:

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  #load data
  df3 = read.csv("C:/Users/X/Desktop/Data/Consolidated_Data_2020-12-27.csv")
  
  #summarize data
  data = reactive({
    req(input$Event)
    df3 <- filter(df3, Side == "Favorite")
    df3 <- df3 %>% filter(Event %in% input$Event)
  })
  
  #plot
  output$plot = renderPlot({
      g = ggplot(data(), aes(x=-(Time.Remaining))) +
      
      geom_line(color = "steelblue", size = 1, aes(y=Original.Line)) + 
      geom_line(color = "#69b3a2", size = 1, aes(y=Live.Line)) +
      labs(title = "Live Line vs Original",
           subtitle = df3$Event,
           y = "Original Line", x = "Time Remaining") +
      facet_wrap(~ Half)
  })
  
}  

ui = basicPage(
  h1("Game"),
  selectInput(inputId = "Event", 
        label = "Choose Game",
        list("Alcorn State Braves @ Vanderbilt Commodores", "DePaul Blue Demons @ Providence Friars")),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Difficult to reproduce this without a minimal example and some data. However, do `print(g)` at the end of the `renderPlot` function. This returns the ggplot cchart.

Comment: Perhaps you could mark the comment as helpful to encourage everyone to keep contributing.

Comment: This sure looks like a duplicate from the word go. And it's in the R-FAQ. It's not at all due to there being a "server" involved.